# Как работает в данном коде decltype?

Tags: c++

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему `decltype` навешивает ссылку:

```
int x = 1;
decltype(x++) t1 = x;//int t1
decltype(++x) t2 = x;//int& t2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) можно посмотреть правила, по которым работает `decltype`. В данном случае интересны:

- if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields T&&;
- if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields T&;
- if the value category of expression is prvalue, then decltype yields T.

`x++` возвращает prvalue, поэтому T = int, `++x` возвращает lvalue, поэтому T& = int&.

Простыми словами в данном случае prvalue отличается от lvalue тем, что второе можно дальше модицифицировать (т.е. `++++x` OK, а `x++++` - нет), это и демонстрируется ссылкой. Подробнее про типы выражений лучше почитать отдельные ответы или документацию.

Comment: Благодарю. Более детальную инфу нашел в книжке Скотта Мейерса.

Answer (score 1):

Префиксные и постфиксные инкременты/декременты не только работают по-разному но и возвращают значения разных типов. Если префикс возвращает `T&`, то постфикс - `T`. Это отражено в [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Increment_and_decrement) к перегрузке этих операторов. Примитивные типы не имеют *функций-членов* типа `operator++`, но работают по тем же правилам. А `decltype` просто берёт тип выражения, вот и всё. Формально всё немного запутаннее, но по сути так понятнее думаю.